# Add new column to data frame, taking existing values within range

Tags: r

I was wondering if anyone knows a simple way to create a new column in a data frame, taking data from an existing column, within a certain range.

For example, I have this data frame

```
range  col1 
1      5
2      4
3      9
4      5
5      2
6      8
7      9
```

I would like to create col2 using the data in col1, and have col2 take values above the range 3

```
range  col1   col2
1      5       0
2      4       0
3      9       0
4      5       5
5      2       2
6      8       8
7      9       9
```

I have tried

```
data$col2 <- data$col1 [which(data$range > 3)) ]
data$col2 <- subset ( data$col1 , data$range >3 )
```

However both of these produce  error:

```
replacement has 4 rows, data has 7
```

Any help greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `ifelse`

```
 transform(data, col2=ifelse(range >3, col1, 0))
 #   range col1 col2
 #1     1    5    0
 #2     2    4    0
 #3     3    9    0
 #4     4    5    5
 #5     5    2    2
 #6     6    8    8
 #7     7    9    9
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do it even without `ifelse` here:

```
data$new <- with(data, (range > 3) * col1)
data
#  range col1 new
#1     1    5   0
#2     2    4   0
#3     3    9   0
#4     4    5   5
#5     5    2   2
#6     6    8   8
#7     7    9   9
```

Comment: As an additional question how would I insert a single value into a single cell and 0 otherwise?

Comment: @user1987097, this is very basic subsetting, e.g. with `df[i,j] <- 99` to insert a single value into a single "cell". Or of you want 0 in other rows, you can first create a new column, `df$mycol <- 0` and then `df$mycol[1] <- 99` to change the first entry in df$mycol.

Comment: @user1987097, if that doesn't answer your _additional_ question, please ask a separate question for it (or take a look at an R tutorial).